# doctrine entity manager doesn't return related rowset

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, entity, one-to-many

I made one to many relation in my entities. 
when try to get related rowset it brings empty result and when try to find parent row from child entity it throws **Entity was not found** exception

here is my initDoctrine

```
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader(
                        'Doctrine',
                        APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/'
        );
        $classLoader->register();
        $config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
        $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
        $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
        $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
        $driver = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(array(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models'));
        $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
        $config->setProxyDir(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../bin/tmp/Proxies');
        $config->setProxyNamespace('App\Proxies');
        $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);
        $connectionSettings = $this->getOption('doctrine');
```

here are my relations

```
/**
* @var array $userFacebooks
* 
* @OneToMany(targetEntity="Application_Model_UserFacebook", mappedBy="user")
*/
protected $userFacebooks;
```

and the parent one

```
/**
* @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application_Model_User", inversedBy="userFacebooks")
* @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id") 
*/
protected $user;
```

Answer (score 0):

The mappings look ok.
Check that all your entity classes are annotated with:

```
/**
 * @entity
 */
class Entity_Name { ... }
```